# PHP Install Script - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, installation

I developed an application using CodeIgniter that I would like to write a nice, user friendly install script for. The biggest problem with this is that CodeIgniter needs configuration manually before this can happen. Does anyone know a way around this? Is this the best way to allow this with minimal configuration?

Comment: You can take a look at a question i asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843763/how-to-determine-if-a-web-application-has-been-installed-and-set-up

Answer (score 1):

If your configuration is built into a form you could include the configuration in the install.

The form would need to validate and verify configuration options such as testing database connections and validating the urls.

Take a look at how WordPress do their 5 minute install. It has a couple of customisations and tests them before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the content out of the config files and write (or overwrite) them.

Answer (score 0):

There are really only 2 areas in a codeigniter project that need manual configuration:

1. the index.php front controller for the application
2. the config.php file in the application directory

There are a ton of configuration options that you can use but basically you're going to need to know:

1. the base URL for the application
2. the base path the application/system folder reside on

You can determine #2 by the path you just installed the application to.

If your application is running at the docroot you could set the base url to:

> "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/";

otherwise you'll need to ask the user what URL this application is supposed to reside at.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a general purpose installer script for CI apps https://github.com/collb/codeigniter-installer 
it has been forked from https://github.com/mikecrittenden/codeigniter-installer with few edits